# Rendering artifacts on edges in Cardboard VR OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es2, virtual-reality

Unity beginner here. I've encountered this weird rendering artifacts in my Cardboard VR app on Android OpenGL ES 2: https://youtu.be/uJm4d3MwbRo
It doesn't occur in WebGL build: http://senovsky.wz.cz/virtualab/index.html
Does someone at least know how to call this artifact? Already tried searching for a solution, but I don't even know what keywords to use.

The app was build using the HelloVR scene from GVR SDK for Unity v1.130.1 https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases and no default settings were changed. I tried changing the default overall quality settings to Ultra and Very High, didn't help.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with anti-aliasing, have you written any rendering code or changed any of the default settings? If you it would be helpful to provide such info

Comment: Good point, I didn't though (question edited).